# Fill list of object parsing html table with linq

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I have a class like

```
public class testClass
{
    private string _field1;
    public string Field1
    {
        get { return _field1; }
        set { _field1 = value; }
    }

    private string _field2;
    public string Field2
    {
        get { return _field2; }
        set { _field2 = value; }
    }

    public testClass(f1, f2)
    {
        _field1 = f1;
        _field2 = f2;
    }
}
```

and I need to parse a simple html table like a recordset, creating a `testClass` object for each `tr`, with its `Field1` and `Field2` containing the `InnerText` of each `td`

Something like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlCode);
List<testClass> Results = (from tr in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
                from td in tr.Descendants("td")
                select new testClass(
                           td.Attributes["name"]=="firstTd".InnerText,
                           td.Attributes["name"]=="secondTd".InnerText
                           )).ToList();
```

But I've no clue on how to do this...

Comment: public string Field1 declared twice, I don't think it can compile. You mean Field2?

Comment: yes, i copied the code... mistake corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

When you're executing the projection in the linq query you should pass the values from the rows into the constructor of your class:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(HtmlCode);
List<testClass> Results = (from tr in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("tr")
                select new testClass(
                           tr.Descendants[0].InnerText,
                           tr.Descendants[1].InnerText
                           )).ToList();
```

The above example relies on the fact that each row will have at least two cells. You probably have to do some error checking to make sure that that is the case.